# How can I set default font size to [bp] instead of [pt] in order to use Lyx with XeTex?

Tags: xetex, errors, lyx, fontsize

I want to use the [bp] font size for the whole document in Lyx 2.0.4 for compilation with XeLatex. My LaTex preamble looks like this: `\usepackage{fontspec} \usepackage{xunicode} \usepackage{xltxtra} \date{}`. If I specify `\documentclass{article}[12bp]` I get these errors: `LaTex Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands` and `LaTex Error: Missing \begin{document}`.

Comment: I would just use `12pt` (`\documentclass[12pt]{article}`), that's quite close, but well supported.

Comment: If I do that I get `LaTex Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands`. But I want to use [bp], as I said, not [pt]. Is that even possible (avoiding the error, of course)?

Comment: The error: consult the documentation of LyX. Using `bp` instead of `pt`: You would have to redefine lots of macros (all font size commands, ...), because `pt` is the standard unit in TeX, not `bp`.

Comment: I couldn't find anything related to that errror. So there's no easy way of using `bp` instead of `pt`. That's a pity, MSWord uses `bp` and it would make it difficult for me to write my thesis, I would end up filling less space.

Comment: @riderplus The reduction in font size is marginal. Hopefully, your are evaluated by content, and not turned down because the thesis is a line too short.

Comment: There error is probably because you've put the option in after the `\documentclass{article}`.  It should be written `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`.

Comment: Regarding the document class error, that's because LyX already puts the document class in for you (even if you don't want it to). So go to Document > Settings > Document Class and under "Custom:" put "12pt"

Comment: @scottkosty That's what I thought. But it should override the setting. I've already put 12pt in there.

Answer (score 3):

The error is nothing to do with the units, just a syntax error in your command which should be

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

you have the `[` after the class name so it is not taken as an optional argument but just as normal text, so you get an error that you can not have text before `\begin{document}` The difference in size between a 12pt font and a 12bp font is no difference at all, you get more difference between two nominally 12pt size fonts of different design, The label attached to a font size is only indirectly related to any actual measurement.  12bp is 12.045pt the difference in height of two nominally 12pt fonts can easily be more than that.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't answer my question. How can I work with `[bp]` instead of `[pt]`? The MSWord font is clearly larger than TeX's `[pt]`.

Comment: By the way, the error still shows up even if I change it as you said. It may be a bug in LyX 2.0.4. About the difference between two nominally 12pt size fonts of different design you are right, but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I've tried putting in the preamble of a LyX 1.6.5 `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` and it gives the same error.